# verify live image in dracut

Tags: openssl, signature, dracut

I have enabled EFI on the target host, enabled secure boot with my own PlatformKey, enabled ipxe bootstrap image where imgverify is used for checking the signature of the initrd. Now I have the challenge to verify rootfs live image in my boot scenario.

```
#!ipxe
set remotestorage http://myserver/repository
ifconf net0

initrd  ${remotestorage}/initrd.img
imgverify initrd.img ${remotestorage}/initrd.img.sig 

kernel  ${remotestorage}/vmlinuz.signed  initrd=initrd-${net0.dhcp/225}.img root=live:${remotestorage}/clusternode.squashfs console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 rd.bootif=0 ifname=net0:${net0/mac} bootdev=net0 ip=${net0/ip}::${net0/gateway}:${net0/netmask}:${net0/hostname}:net0:off nameserver=${net0/dns}

boot
```

Any idea how to implement verification of the signature for clusternode.squashfs?